# Distribution of minimum of infinite independent and uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

We define an infinite sequence of independent random variables $U1, U2, U3, ...$, uniformly distributed across the open interval $(0,1)$.

We also define another random variable, $N=\min \{ n\in \mathbb{N} | \prod ^{n+1}_{j=1}U_{j} < e^{- \lambda}\}$

How is N distributed?

**What I've done so far:**

To my understanding, we need to find $P(N=k)$:

(1). As for the first step, I was trying to understand what is the set that N is distributed from.
So all set members follow
$$\begin{aligned}\prod ^{n+1}_{j=1}U_{j} <e^{-\lambda }\\
\downarrow \\
\ln \left( \prod ^{n+1}_{j=1}U_{j}\right)  <-\lambda \\
\downarrow \\
\sum ^{n+1}_{j=1}\ln \left( U_{j}\right)  <-\lambda \\
\downarrow \\
-\dfrac{1}{\lambda }\sum ^{n+1}_{j=1}\ln \left( U_{j}\right)  > 1 \end{aligned}$$

Denotating $-\dfrac{1}{\lambda }\ln \left( U_{i}\right) = X_{i}$, I found that for any $i\in \left[ n\right]$, $X_{i}$ is distributed exponentially with expected value $\lambda$.
So the sum $X1 + X2 + X3 + ... $ follows a Gamma distribution with parameters $(n, \lambda)$.

(2). If $N=k$, then for any $i\in \left[ k - 1 \right]$, $\prod ^{i+1}_{j=1}U_{j}\geq e^{- \lambda}$, and for any $i \geq k$, $\prod ^{i+1}_{j=1}U_{j} < e^{- \lambda}$.

(3). I wanted to calculate $P(N=k)$ using the law of total probability, but I found it difficult to understand what's $P(min \; is \; i)$ due to (2)

Would appriciate some help! Thanks!

Comment: Rather than starting with the general case, you should start with $P(N = 1)$ and $P(N =2)$.